# Weird session management bug when mixing ring's `wrap-defaults`' and lib-noir's `wrap-noir-session`

Tags: clojure, ring, lib-noir

I have a `ring` webapp that uses `noir.session` as follows:

```
(def app (-> app-routes
         (session/wrap-noir-session)
         (wrap-defaults site-defaults))) ; both from ring.middleware.defaults
```

However, it seems like session variables are lost between the requests. The server keeps sending a `Set-Cookie` header even though the client provides the `Cookie` header.

Using trial and error, I found out that when I disable ring's anti-forgery wrapper as follows, the same session lives across requests:

```
(def app (-> app-routes
         (session/wrap-noir-session)
         (wrap-defaults (assoc-in site-defaults [:security :anti-forgery] false))))
```

but of course I don't want that. Why is this, and how can I fix my problem without risking CSRF attacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsing the source code of all involved middleware, I found out that lib-noir's `wrap-noir-session` re-implements parts of ring's `wrap-session`. That lead me to the following experiment:

```
(def app (-> app-routes
         (session/wrap-noir-session {:store (memory-store)})
         (wrap-defaults (assoc site-defaults :session false))))
```

Here as well, sessions live across requests.

Here's the culprit: `wrap-defaults` already applies `wrap-session`, so when the `wrap-noir-session` handler is listed as well, `wrap-session` is actually invoked twice.

The final solution couldn't be simpler: **Use `wrap-noir-session*` instead.** According to the docs, it *"expects that wrap-session has already been used."* It seems that the contrary is true for `wrap-noir-session`.

```
(def app (-> app-routes
         (session/wrap-noir-session*)
         (wrap-defaults site-defaults)))
```

Hopefully, this will save you some time.